# Dotnet template conflict (project templates)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying to create a project template via the `dotnet new wpflib` command. Running the command results in the following error:

[image]

Unable to resolve the template, the following installed templates are conflicting... and
Uninstall the templates or the packages to keep only one template from the list

Any idea how to solve this? I do not want to uninstall all wpflib templates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out for me that the `groupIdentity` field of the `template.json` seems to need to be unique. I assumed it could be the same like other templates that I want to publish because they might be associated to the same 'group' of templates. But, if they were, I received the same issue like you.

For example, I made some item-templates, and all of them had the same `groupIdentity` value:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "TomsCompany",
  "classifications": [ "Common", "Code" ],
  "identity": "TomsCompany.ItemTemplates.DependencyInjectionService",
  "groupIdentity": "TomsCompanyTemplates", // <-- this needs to be unique for each template.json
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  ...
}
```